# Highmaps, how to load local mapdata

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highmaps

By the highmaps demo, I load the maps successfully.
the script is:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/cn/custom/cn-all-sar-taiwan.js"></script>
```

(The highmaps has been loaded by require.js)

The highmap directives:(I like angular.js)

```
$scope.$on('mapInit', function(){

                element.highcharts('Map',{
                    title : {
                        text : 'Highmaps basic demo'
                    },

                    subtitle : {
                        text : 'Source map'
                    },

                    mapNavigation: {
                        enabled: true,
                        buttonOptions: {
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    },

                    colorAxis: {
                        min: 0
                    },

                    series : [{
                        data : data,
                        mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/cn/custom/cn-all-sar-taiwan'],
                        joinBy: 'hc-key',
                        name: 'Random data',
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                color: '#BADA55'
                            }
                        },
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.name}'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            });
```

This is successful! But when I download the files:

As local files,

```
<script src="./maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="./mapdata/countries/cn/cn-all-sar-taiwan.js"></script>'
```

And change the mapdata:
mapData: `Highcharts.maps['countries/cn/cn-all-sar-taiwan']`

The map is not shown again！

I think the mapData has something wrong, so I tried to search the highmaps API, there is nothing...

Please help me!

Comment: Could you provide complete codes including the html,css, angular controller, etc? Ideally if you can create in the jsfiddle and provide the link? So people can view the details and help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Have you any errors in the console ?